# Nested set model in higher dimensions

Tags: database-design, hierarchy, tree

The nested set structure is well-known and involves using `left` and `right` values to denote the relative heirarchy of nodes on one axis.

Is there a generalization of this structure to higher dimensions?  For example, a 2-dimensional case could be used for describing nested bounding boxes for the elements of an image.  The bounding box for a car contains bounding boxes for the wheels, the spokes of the wheels, and so on.

Is it reasonable to simply extend the basic form by adding `top` and `bottom` columns and checking for nesting with similar comparisons?  Does this work for even higher dimensions?  Any non-obvious caveats to this approach?

Edit: perhaps I should clarify, I'm aiming for RDBMS/SQL approaches here.

Comment: For any number of dimensions set A contain set B if for every axis projection of A contain projection of B. If one or more projections intersects then A intersect B. If none of projections of A contain or intersect any projection of B then A and B has nullary intersection.